# Arrow not pointing the right way

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can you help me with the arrow? And also, how do I put `sim(u_{a},u_{j})` inside the area surrounded by the arrow?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \centering 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
    \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,
    nodes={minimum size=5ex,anchor=center,draw},column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep={-\pgflinewidth},
    nodes in empty cells,
    ]{
        & $i_{1}$& $i_{2}$ & $i_{3}$ & \dots &$ i_{k}$    & $ i_{a}$  & \dots &$ i_{n}$ \\ 
        $u_{1}$ & & 5 &   & 2 & 4    &    &  &  \\ 
        $u_{2}$ & & 5 & 4 &  & 5 &   & 4  &\\ 
        \dots & &   &   &  &   & 1 & 1 & 2   \\ 
        $u_{j}$ & 3 &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 3 & &  0 \\ 
        $u_{a}$ & & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 2 &  & 4 &  &\color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \\ 
        \dots& & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 2 &  & 4 &  &\color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \\ 
        $u_{6}$ & & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 2 &  & 4 &  &\color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \\
    };
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[orange!30](m-2-5.north west)rectangle(m-6-5.south east);
    \fill[gray!30](m-2-5.north west)rectangle(m-8-6.south east);
    \fill[orange!30](m-4-2.north west)rectangle(m-4-9.south east);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[-latex](m-6-9.east)--+(1,0)node[above right]{User-based similarity measure}|-(m-5-9.east);
    \node[left]at(m-4-1.west){Active User};
    \draw[-latex](m-2-5.north west)--+(1,0)node[below right]{Item-based }|-(m-8-6.south east);


    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The one that says Item Based `\draw[-latex](m-2-5.north west)--+(1,0)node[below right]{Item-based }|-(m-8-6.south east)`. It has to go between columns `i_{k}` and `i_{a}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixes the arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \centering 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
    \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,
    nodes={minimum size=5ex,anchor=center,draw},column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep={-\pgflinewidth},
    nodes in empty cells,
    ]{
        & $i_{1}$& $i_{2}$ & $i_{3}$ & \dots &$ i_{k}$    & $ i_{a}$  & \dots &$ i_{n}$ \\ 
        $u_{1}$ & & 5 &   & 2 & 4    &    &  &  \\ 
        $u_{2}$ & & 5 & 4 &  & 5 &   & 4  &\\ 
        \dots & &   &   &  &   & 1 & 1 & 2   \\ 
        $u_{j}$ & 3 &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 3 & &  0 \\ 
        $u_{a}$ & & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 2 &  & 4 &  &\color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \\ 
        \dots& & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 2 &  & 4 &  &\color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \\ 
        $u_{6}$ & & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 2 &  & 4 &  &\color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \\
    };
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[orange!30](m-2-5.north west)rectangle(m-6-5.south east);
    \fill[gray!30](m-2-5.north west)rectangle(m-8-6.south east);
    \fill[orange!30](m-4-2.north west)rectangle(m-4-9.south east);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[-latex](m-6-9.east)--+(1,0)node[above right]{User-based similarity measure}|-(m-5-9.east);
    \node[left]at(m-4-1.west){Active User};
    \draw[latex-] (m-1-6) -- ++ (-1,1) node[above left,align=left]
    {Item preference score is\\ predicted for active user};
    \draw[-latex]([xshift=-2pt]m-8-6.south east)--++(0,-1) -| 
    ([xshift=2pt]m-8-5.south west)
    node[pos=0.25,below]{Item-based}
    node[pos=0.25,above,font=\tiny]{$\mathrm{sim}(u_{a},u_{j})$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this is an alternative way (not necessarily better) to obtain the same result. Instead of filling on the background layer (which is absolutely fine) this fills the cells via styles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,b/.style={text=blue,font=\bfseries}]
    \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,
    nodes={minimum size=5ex,anchor=center,draw},
    row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none,fill=none}},
    column 5/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
    column 6/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
    row 4/.style={nodes={fill=orange!30}},
    column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none,fill=none}},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep={-\pgflinewidth},
    nodes in empty cells,
    ]{
        & $i_{1}$& $i_{2}$ & $i_{3}$ & \dots &$ i_{k}$    & $ i_{a}$  & \dots &$ i_{n}$ \\ 
        $u_{1}$ & & 5 &   & 2 & 4    &    &  &  \\ 
        $u_{2}$ & & 5 & 4 &  & 5 &   & 4  &\\ 
        |[fill=none]|\dots & &   &   &  &   & 1 & 1 & 2   \\ 
        $u_{j}$ & 3 &  & |[b]| ? &  & |[b]| ? & 3 & &  0 \\ 
        $u_{a}$ & & |[b]| ? & 2 &  & 4 &  &|[b]| ? &  \\ 
        \dots& & |[b]| ? & 2 &  & 4 &  &|[b]| ? &  \\ 
        $u_{6}$ & & |[b]| ? & 2 &  & 4 &  &|[b]| ? &  \\
    };
    \draw[-latex](m-6-9.east)--+(1,0)node[above right]{User-based similarity measure}|-(m-5-9.east);
    \node[left]at(m-4-1.west){Active User};
    \draw[latex-] (m-1-6) -- ++ (-1,1) node[above left,align=left]
    {Item preference score is\\ predicted for active user};
    \draw[-latex]([xshift=-2pt]m-8-6.south east)--++(0,-1) -| 
    ([xshift=2pt]m-8-5.south west)
    node[pos=0.25,below]{Item-based}
    node[pos=0.25,above,font=\tiny]{$\mathrm{sim}(u_{a},u_{j})$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I needed that arrow also! Thank you! But I was referring myself to the one between columns 4 and 5 and row 7: the one that says "Item based similarity measure" in the original screenshot

Comment: @NaveganTeX I added such an arrow. Does it connect the right cells? (The coloring of your desired screen shot and the output differ a bit.)

Comment: Yes, its 'perfect!!! One last thing:  how do I put sim(u_{a},u_{j}) and sim(i_{a},i_{k}) inside the area surrounded by the arrow?

Comment: @NaveganTeX I added it but had to make the loop a bit wider to make it fit.

Comment: Can I make it a standalone document? Because it is much easier to resize when I add it to the whole document...

Comment: @NaveganTeX Yes, as long as you remove `\centering`. I added a second version that fills in a different way, and is standalone.

Comment: Perfect! Now it looks awesome. I am working on the coloring. I'll get back if I can't solve it. Thank you Marmot!!!

Comment: Marmot! Can you add the other similarity? Meaning,` {$\mathrm{sim}(u_{a},u_{j})$};` the user based one. I tried but I failed :(